# How to troubleshoot incompatibility of Oracle drivers?

Tags: database, oracle, delphi, version, driver

Abstract:
I compiled an application in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and to access Oracle database I used the dbxora.dll driver.

The old version of this same application used the driver dbexpora.dll.

On machines running Oracle Client 10.2 the application does not work and the following error message appears:

***DBX Error: Error Code: -1***

On my machine and others with the Oracle Client 11.1 or 11.2 version it works normally.

The problem is that even putting dbexpora.dll together with the executable on machines with ORA 10.2 does not work.

Follows the connection code with Oracle

```
[dmconnectionOracle]
  LibraryName    = dbxora.dll
  GetDriverFunc  = getSQLDriverORACLE
  VendorLib      = oci.dll
  DatabaseServer = Oracle
  Drivername     = Oracle
  DataBase       = XYZ
  SQLDialect     = 3
  User_Name      = XXXXXXX
  Password       = XXXXXXX
```

Questions:

1 -Is this a problem with the Oracle version or the Delphi build?

2 - What is the difference between dbexpora and dbxora?

Comment: On the Oracle Client 10.2 machines, do you still get the error if you deploy dbxora.dll **and** oci.dll to your app's directory?

Comment: On the ORA10.2 machines I put both dlls even so they do not work. I would like to know if compiling in Delphi already points the corresponding Oracle drivers.

Comment: Compiling a Delphi app does not change the drivers on the client machine.  DBExpress (DBX) uses the first instances of DBCConnections.Ini and DBXDrivers.Ini it finds (using the usual Windows search method) on the client machine, so if you haven't deployed those, that could be your problem.  Regardless, no-one else can debug this for you.  You will need to debug this on a machine where the error occurs.  You could use Delphi's remote debugging to do this from your development machine - see the online help for how to do this.

Comment: if I put dbxdrivers.ini and dbxconnection.ini in the executable directory it can fetch them?

Comment: Well, the OS should be able to find them.